# How to create route in shopware 6 cloud App to register a route in different platform's webhook

Tags: api, webhooks, shopware, shopware6, shopware6-api

I'm trying to create a route in shopware 6 cloud app so that I can **register** that route in different platform's **Webhook** and work in my own programming language known and work with **Shopware 6** order API for transaction changes.

I didn't get any sufficient or respective doc. or plugin in github.

So can someone help me out with this ?

Answer (score 1):

This question touches on multiple different topics. I'll try to break it down.

> I'm trying to create a route

Plugin: [Add custom controller](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/add-custom-controller)
App: [Add custom endpoint](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/app-scripts/custom-endpoints#custom-endpoints)

> so that I can register that route in different platform's Webhook

I assume you're talking about [Shopware's webhooks](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/apps/app-base-guide#webhooks) here. If you want to add to the list of [available webhook events](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/resources/references/app-reference/webhook-events-reference), you first must [dispatch a custom event](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/event/add-custom-event). To make the event hookable, the event class simply has to implement `Shopware\Core\Framework\Event\FlowEventAware`. Take a look at the [`ContactFormEvent`](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/e8bfb676e6ffe37df629184798c9c232cac4bca5/src/Core/Content/ContactForm/Event/ContactFormEvent.php) as an example on how to implement it.

Comment: No i asked about how to create route in shopware app. I didn't talk about shopware webhook.

Comment: can we create route in shopware app?

Comment: before downgrade a question please make sure you understand the question !
it's really bad or demotivated for someone who's new to these platforms.

Comment: I updated the answer. To avoid people become confused by your question maybe try be a little more specific. For example why you need that endpoint is completely irrelevant to the question. If you don't refer to Shopware's webhooks, don't mention webhooks for example. Also app is a generic term which now covers both formerly called plugins and apps. If you can refer to them as cloud apps instead, it would clear things up, as that's their main use case with cloud hosted shops.

Comment: actually i want the route to add in different platform's webhook so that i can get information on http and then i can work with shopware order api.